# {php} is not working in latest smarty while using SmartyBC class file

Tags: php, smarty3

I have came across my first issue and it has to deal with PHP in smarty. I read the smarty manual where it said to include the SmartyBC.class.php file instead of the regular Smarty.class.php file and i did change the default file to the BC file. I went into my .tpl file and add `{php}Messages::displayMsg();{/php}` to show my "wrong password" message when i enter incorrect details to test to see if it works. I get this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template
>   "file:/var/www/falonde.local/public_html/views/Admin/login.tpl" on
>   line 51 "{php}" {php}{/php} tags not allowed. Use SmartyBC to enable
>   them <-- thrown in
>   /var/www/falonde.local/public_html/libs/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
>   on line 51

I am including it. Its included, smarty works if i remove the php code. But it won't show my error message at all. It gives me that. And i have included SmartyBC.class.php where i included the Smarty.class.php before. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: is your code using `new Smarty()` or `new SmartyBC()` ? https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl

Comment: Heyo! Thanks for your comment. Just found out that i needed to use SmartyBC() so i changed it. But my messages are still not being shown. I no longer get the error, but my error bootstrap notification is still not showing up. I even ran it through a .php file and it worked. Just not in the smarty.tpl.... whats going on you think/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you previously had

```
require_once('path/to/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();
```

change it to

```
require_once('path/to/smarty/libs/SmartyBC.class.php');
$smarty = new SmartyBC();
```

https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl

Comment: I just did that a few seconds ago, but my error messages are not showing up. New issue. It shows up when i do "Messages::displayMsg();" in a regular php file but with the template, its still not showing my message.

Comment: If this solves the `{php}{/php} tags not allowed` issue, then anything further is a new stack overflow question.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer will be marked as correct as soon as it gives me the chance. lolol

Comment: Whatever you're doing I would strongly recommend avoiding `{php}` tags in smarty as much as possible, you could assign your `Messages` object to smarty and still do `{$Messages->displayMsg()}` if its a non-static method?

Comment: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.static.classes.tpl What version of smarty are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164061/discussion-between-scuzzy-and-jarrod-estepp).