# If Else Operations doesnt work in .tpl file

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I have this tpl file code which will represent 2 factor authentication validation

```
<form 
     action="../tiki-two_factor_validator.php" 
     method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">
            <label for="twoFactor">
                   {if isset($_GET.error)}
                       <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            {$_GET.error}
                        </div>
                    {else}
                        We send to your email two-factor authentication code
                    {/if}
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="twoFactor" name="twoFactor" placeholder="Two-Factor Code" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
</form>
```

but i got in html something like this:

[image]

What could be causing this error?

Edit* I have no problems with PHP, everything works as expected

```
if (isset($result[0])) {
        $attempts = $result[0]['attempts'] + 1;
        $query = "UPDATE tiki_2fa_tokens SET attempts = '$attempts' WHERE token = '$token'";
        TikiDb::get()->query($query);
    } else {
        header("Location: http://127.0.0.1:8080/tikiTwoFactor?error=Wrong token, please try again");
        exit();
    }
require_once('vendor_bundled/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->display('/templates/tiki_two_factor_auth.tpl');
```

when i am trying to access the page using route path (http://127.0.0.1:8080/tikiTwoFactor):

```
tiki_route_attempt(
        '|^tikiTwoFactor$|',
        'templates/tiki_two_factor_auth.tpl'
);
```

i am getting this errors in brawser, but when i am accessing using folder path (http://127.0.0.1:8080/tiki-two_factor_validator.php) everything seems okay

[image]

Comment: I don't know the syntax intimately, but basing it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808294/what-are-tpl-files-php-web-design I think if you want to use regular PHP code which isn't part of the templating language, you seem to have to put it inside a `{php} ... {/php}` block. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446851/using-php-code-in-smarty-tpl-file

Comment: @ADyson didnt work(

Comment: What template engine and what version?

Comment: @ArsenMkrtumian in what way? What exactly was the result? I have assumed these are Smarty templates (based on the file extension and the content), but please correct me if that's not the case. Also, one of the answers in those posts notes that you may only be able to get this functionality using SmartyBC, if you have a newer version. Did you try that? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493702/php-is-not-working-in-latest-smarty-while-using-smartybc-class-file. I've never used Smarty but there seems to be plenty of info about this issue online if you care to do some basic searching

Comment: @shingo Smarty - .tpl i cant find the version (

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is Smarty even evaluated on this page after all? Would dumping `$_GET` result in a proper dump, containing what you would expect, or anything else?

Comment: @ADyson I tried a lot of things, now I’ll update the php code so you can see

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried a lot of things, now I’ll update the php code so you can see

Comment: Please be warned that your SQL query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked. Did you try to dump the variable?

Comment: @NicoHaase I know about it, thanks, But for first i need to solve the problem with tpl file

Comment: `Smarty::SMARTY_VERSION` is the version. Is this the whole tpl file content? Maybe there is a mustache ahead that caused the template to not rendered correctly. Try `$smarty->fetch(...)` to see the compiled php file.

Comment: @shingo the version is 4.3.4

Comment: @NicoHaase now i get string(66) "Unable to load template 'file:/templates/tiki_two_factor_auth.tpl'" but path that i wrote is correct

Comment: @NicoHaase Please check the last edit

Comment: @ADyson Please check the last edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in displaying the interaction between a file like tpl and the router, I changed all the headers to the default smarty ->assign method and everything worked

```
        if ($seconds > 1800) {
            $smarty->assign('error', 'Expired token, please login again');
        } else {
            $attempts = $result[0]['attempts'] + 1;
            $query = "UPDATE tiki_2fa_tokens SET attempts = '$attempts' WHERE token = '$token'";
            TikiDb::get()->query($query);
        }
```

.tpl

```
                    {if $error}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            {$error}
                        </div>
                    {else}
                        We send to your email two-factor authentication code
                    {/if}
```

result
[image]

Comment: Hi. If your answer solves the problem please consider accepting it as an answer. This will benefit future users who find your question in a search. They will see that a solution exists. For details on accepting answers see this [Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Before accepting your answer please post debug messages as text. Stack Overflow [discourages use of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) for code/error/debug/log messages.

Comment: @kofeigen Hi, i can accept it in 19 hours